# Looking for a reliable and efficient Java library for Formal Concept Analysis

Tags: java, concept-analysis

I need to perform [Formal Concept Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_concept_analysis) on the fly and am looking for an efficient SDK for calculating the concepts for a given context. There are a lot of research tools around but I'm looking for something supported and reliable.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I have heard about - http://code.google.com/p/colibri-java/

Comment: A possibly helpful link from the Wikipedia article    http://www.fcahome.org.uk/fcasoftware.html

Answer (score 1):

## Frameworks / Libraries

FCA Home suggests a list of [software](http://www.fcahome.org.uk/fcasoftware.html), including (few) Java solutions:

- [Colibri-Java](http://code.google.com/p/colibri-java/)
- [FCAlib](http://fcalib.googlecode.com/)

## Reuse or Learn from Existing Tools

Maybe some FCA exploration tools and academic projects provide source code you could inspire yourself from, or directly reuse if their licenses permit such use:

- [ToscanaJ](http://toscanaj.sourceforge.net/)
- [Galicia](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~galicia/)
- [CORON](http://hal.inria.fr/docs/00/06/46/87/PDF/A05-R-015.pdf)
- [ConExp](http://conexp.sourceforge.net/)

## Roll Out Your Own

Or, as a last resort, you'll need to roll out your own based on either (or a combination of):

- existing solutions available in other languages (maybe you can use a binding?),
- experimental research (like [this one](http://biblio.info.ucl.ac.be/2005/285798.pdf) and [a herd of other ones](http://scholar.google.fr/scholar?q=fca%20%22formal%20concept%20analysis%22&hl=en&btnG=Search&as_sdt=1,5&as_sdtp=on)).